# Android webview do not scroll down accessibility marker

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

In my app webview have HTML text ,when I run app in accessibility mode (Talkback) it do not move accessibility marker down to content on webview, using two finger swipe I can swipe down.

How can I set webview so that it marker scroll down when user taps.

Comment: Is this a webview you added to a native application?  Or is this like a PhoneGap app?  A little more detail...

Comment: This is in native app,and the content is downloaded then set inside webview.

Comment: How the web content got there is insignificant, compared to how you attach the WebView to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Not many details, hard to be sure.  One thing to remember, is that native web views are not necessarily accessible by default.  Make sure when you attach your WebView you set its accessibilityDelegate.

```
yourWebView.setAccessibilityDelegate(new AccessibilityDelegate());
```

Comment: Hi @ChrisCM

webview is in XML layout.I am already using this method on webview still no success.
What you mean by native webview?

Comment: Also I am using this method to load text on webview:
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", completeHtml.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);

Comment: This is incorrect. WebViews on Android have been accessible by default since KitKat.

Comment: "Not many details, hard to be sure...", Android version would be one of those important details.

Answer (score 0):

On recent versions of Android, Chrome and WebView use exactly the same engine.

Test the same URL / HTML content in Chrome on the same device. If it's not accessible there, then the problem is with your content. Post a new question about the particular content.

If the same URL / HTML content works in Chrome but not in the WebView in your app, the problem is probably with your app's code. Perhaps you're intercepting hover events, preventing the WebView from having a chance to implement touch exploration.